# Using map in a void context?

Tags: perl

I have this code:

```
my %events = (); 
map { $events{$_} => 1 } @event_ids;
map { $events{$_} => 2 } @teen_event_ids;
map { $events{$_} => 3 } @kids_event_ids;
```

Although the arrays have data, the content of `%events` is turning up empty.

Answer (score 4):

`%events` wasn't changed because you never even tried to change `%events` (except for emptying it when it was already empty)! I think you meant to do

```
my %events; 
map { $events{$_} = 1 } @event_ids;
map { $events{$_} = 2 } @teen_event_ids;
map { $events{$_} = 3 } @kids_event_ids;
```

Using `map` in void context is frowned-upon. The following are more familiar:

```
my %events = (
   ( map { $_ => 1 } @event_ids ),
   ( map { $_ => 2 } @teen_event_ids ),
   ( map { $_ => 3 } @kids_event_ids ),
);
```

or

```
my %events; 
$events{$_} = 1 for @event_ids;
$events{$_} = 2 for @teen_event_ids;
$events{$_} = 3 for @kids_event_ids;
```

---

Technically, you can use parens around `map`'s operands (`map( BLOCK LIST )`), but it looks weird, so I put the parens around then entire `map`.

Answer (score 1):

That's... not really the way `map` is intended to be used.  It transforms a list into a different list and returns the resulting list.  It's not meant to change a list (or hash) in-place.

Try this instead:

```
my %events = (); 
$events{$_} = 1 for @event_ids;
$events{$_} = 2 for @teen_event_ids;
$events{$_} = 3 for @kids_event_ids;
```

or, if you specifically want to include a `map`:

```
my %events = map { $_ => 1 } @event_ids;
$events{$_} = 2 for @teen_event_ids;
$events{$_} = 3 for @kids_event_ids;
```

or even:

```
my %events = map { $_ => find_event_category($_) } @event_ids, @teen_event_ids, @kids_event_ids;
```

where `find_event_category` is a function which determines whether an id is for a teen or kids event and returns `1`, `2`, or `3` as appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

OK, it's time to get some sleep. Should just be using `=` not the fat arrow, `=>`.

Comment: Or just use a for:  `$events{$_} = 1 for @event_ids;`

Comment: Or just do them all at once: `$events{$_}++ for @event_ids, @teens, @kids;`

Comment: @TLP, did you try that? The `++` is activated for each element in all the arrays, which act as one long list.

Comment: Maybe TLP meant `++$events{$_} for (@event_ids)x1, (@teens)x2, (@kids)x3;` ;)

Comment: Using `map` when you meant to use `for` is dirty.